# Does pass by reference works in case of String

Tags: java, string

In java if Objects are pass by reference than in following code,

```
String str1 = new String("abc");
String str2 = str1;
str1 = str1+"def";
System.out.println("str2 : "+str2);
```

Even after modifying string `str1` after assigning it to string `str2` I get output as `str2 : "abc"`
instead of "abcdef"
so pass by reference does not work in case of string??

Comment: Java doesn't pass by reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: 'Does pass by reference work': no. There is no pass by reference in Java. 'In case of String': irrelevant.

Comment: Technically speaking, the code in the question does not "pass" at all (by reference or otherwise), since there is no function call involved.

Answer (score 1):

Instances of String in Java are immutable. When you think you're modifying a String actually what you're doing is to create a new one.

Comment: In case of wrapper (eg Integer) i get the same result. what is the reason for that ??

Comment: @Zues Wrappers are immutable too.

Comment: thanx bro!!. it helped me alot

Comment: You're welcome @Zues. Feel free to approve the answer.